# Explain to me how my _.memoize function is working step by step

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
_.memoize = function(func) { //declare memoize function that takes in a function
    var memorized = {} //declare an object literal which will store each function call and result
    return function () { //not sure why I need to return an anonymous function
      var memo = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, arguments) //Use Array method of slice on the arguments array of the func function save it to variable memo
      if(memorized[memo]){ //if the key of arguments exists in the memoized object
        return memorized[memo]; //return the associated value
      } else { //if the key of arguments does not exist in the object
        return memorized[memo] = func.apply(null, arguments); //call func with the arguments and save the result into the memoized object with the argument array as a key
      }
    }
  };
```

I tried to explain it myself line by line to see if my thinking and knowledge is correct.

I guess my only question is why do we need an anonymous function call inside the function? Also how does apply know which arguments we're talking about.

Comment: "*store each function call*" - of what function?

Comment: It's *the* [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Using `memo` instead should've worked as well.

Comment: Where did you find this function? It's horrible - it should be `slice.apply(arguments)` and `func.apply(this, arguments)`.

Comment: i wrote the whole thing. okay whats the difference between those two version of the statements vs what I wrote? thanks for the feedback btw

Comment: Wait you wrote it but don't understand how it's working? oO `slice` expects no arguments, if any they should be `0` and `arguments.length`. Passing `this` through is not strictly necessary if `func` doesn't use the keyword, but good practice.